# string Join List and items

Tags: c#, string

I need to join strings and `List<string>` items. My Code

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2" };
string item3 = "item3";

string result = string.Join(",", list, item3);
```

The result is

```
//System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String],item3
```

instead of expected

```
//item1,item2,item3
```

What is the most elegant approach so solve this inline? There could be multiple `List<string>` and multiple `string` and each of them can be null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can concatenate all strings using `Concat` (without changing the original list!) and `Join` that enumerable:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2" };
string item3 = "item3";

string result = string.Join(",", list.Concat(new string[] { item3 }));
// result = item1,item2,item3
```

The problem with your current code is that it calls `string.Join(string, params IEnumerable<object>)`: it will treat `list` as an object, not a lis of objects.

Comment: There could be multiple `List<string>`

Comment: Then concatenate those lists too.

Answer (score 2):

If the final result needs to be a single `string` then you can use something like. This will first join the `list` into single `string` and then will join it with `item3`:

```
string result = string.Join (",", string.Join (",", list), item3);
```

For each extra `List` you could add additional `string.Join (",", otherList)` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2" };

string item3 = "item3";

list.Add(item3);

string result = string.Join(",",list);

//result will have: item1,item2,item3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2" };
        string item3 = "item3";

        list.Add(item3);
        //This will result to "item1, item2, item3
        string result = String.Join(",", list.ToArray());

        //If you don't want to change the list without adding anything on it:         
        string result = String.Join(", ", list.ToArray()) + ", " + item3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge all the lists and individual values into a single list. One way to do that is by using a method that takes any number of arguments, checks their type, and outputs a concatenated list.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2" };
string item3 = "item3";
List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "item4", "item5" };
string item6 = "item6";

string result = string.Join(",", GetConcatenatedValues(list, item3, list2, item6));

public List<string> GetConcatenatedValues(params object[] args)
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    foreach (var entry in args
    {
        if (entry is List<string>)
            results.AddRange(entry as List<string>);
        else
            results.Add(entry.ToString());
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: You could improve that code by returning `IEnumerable` (using `yield return`) and checking on `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `List<string>`. Besides that: nice solution!

Comment: Agreed. That could be an improvement to make. I'll leave that up to others to decide, if they want to do it or not :)

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
string result = string.Join(",", list.Concat(new string[1] { item3 }));
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman It does exactly what was required: gets a list of strings, adds another string at the end and then produces a comma-separated string of all that strings.

Comment: Why not explain that to the OP?